# Excel conditional formatting -Show only a part of it in another sheet

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In cell A1 a date time is given. in cell B1 i have given Now(). In cell C1 the time difference is calculated in hh:mm:ss format.

Ex:

A1(target time)

## 08/03/2013 11:00:00 P.M

B1(current time)

## 08/03/2013 09:00:00 P.M.

C1(remaining time)

## 02:00:00

i have done conditional formatting on cell C1 for 100 rows containing values in hh:mm:ss format .Those 100 values are having more than one conditional formatting.

As the time passes by the value of cell C1 is decreasing and will finally come to 00:00:00

Now CF are given as GREEN for >10:00:00, AMBER for between 04:00:00 to 09:59:59, RED for between 00:00:01 to 03:59:59,BLACK for <=00:00:00

So the number of RED cells are not fixed as some from RED are becoming BLACK  and some are entering RED from AMBER with the time passing by.

What i want is:

In sheet2 i need only the values that are red in colour i.e. between 00:00:01 to 03:59:59

Answer (score 0):

If red colored cells are always between `00:00:01` and `03:59:59` then you can get the value you want in `Sheet2` by just looking at values.

On Sheet2 this formula would retrieve red cells:

```
=IF(AND(C1 > 1/86400,C1 < 14399/86400),C1,"")
```

`86400` is the number of seconds in a day (60*60/24). `1` represents `00:00:01` and `14399` represents `03:59:59`.

So if any cell in column C on Sheet1 is between `00:00:01` and `03:59:59` show in Sheet2 else leave it blank.

Does that help?

Comment: This is working for the particular cell mentioned in the formula though the colour is not reflecting. How to bring the colour ?

Comment: You can't 'bring' the color. You'd need to set up conditional formatting on your other sheet.